# asp.net web api login and register routes without controller prefix

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am having difficulties defining login and register routes without a controller prefix. I have a user controller that has the methods for "Login(String email, String password)" and "Register(User user)".

The format I want to achieve is "api/login" and "api/register".

I tried the following code for login:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "Login",
      routeTemplate: "api/login",
      defaults: new { controller = "Users", action = "Login" });
```

However, I get this error:

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:50145/api/login/'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'login'."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that with attribute routing and the tilde sign it is possible to overwrite prefixes

```
[Route("~/api/login")]
```